# ReactJS - Location ... did not match any specific any routes

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router

I used webpack to bundle all my files.
I have a bundle.js file in a directory with an index.html

When i open it in browser it gives me an error :-

```
Warning: [react-router] Location "/home/vivek/Desktop/prismo-front/build/index.html" did not match any routes
```

My file directory looks like this : -

[image]

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, 
   shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
  <title>Prismo</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
    </noscript>
    <div id="root">ds</div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bundle.js" charset="utf-8">
  </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the following to serve your files locally.

1. Install: npm install -g http-server.
2. cd into `build`
3. run `http-server`
4. go to `http://localhost:8080/` in browser

OR upload your files to a server and you won't get this problem. You can't use run your index.html file locally as it doesn't play nicely with History which is used for React Router.

Comment: How to run the http-server ?

I am getting this error :- 
`No command 'run' found:`

When i did :- 
`run http-server`

Comment: You don't type run just `http-server`

Comment: Thanks ! 
Any more information on why we can't use history on local files.
How is 'history' with http-server ? 

Also i can run this on normal xampp server also right ?

Comment: Because it's trying to match "/home/vivek/Desktop/prismo-front/build/index.html" in React-Router. "/" doesn't exist in this context if you're loading it locally.